# Write acess violation while writing data to array

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I'm trying to access the `SDL_Rect*` array in the constructor, but everytime I do I get a `Write access violation`. I tried multiple solutions but none worked for me.

What I currently have: I made an array of a `struct`: `SDL_Rect* rects[50]`.

I then try to access the data using

```
this->rects[index]->x = x;
```

And this results in a write acess violation.

I also tried to remove the array (`SDL_Rect* rects`) and access the data using

```
rects->y = y;
```

But this also resulted in a write access violation.

An array would be wonderful, but every time I try I get the before-mentioned exception, is this not achievable?

---

rects.cpp:

```
namespace SDLGamecore {
namespace graphics {

    Rects::Rects(int x, int y, int w, int h)
    {
        rects->x = x; //Exception thrown: write access violation.
        rects->y = y;
        rects->w = w;
        rects->h = h;
        rectsSize += 1; //this works...
    }

    Rects::~Rects()
    {
        delete[] rects;
    }

    SDL_Rect* Rects::getRects()
    {
        return rects;
    }

    int Rects::getRectsSize()
    {
        return rectsSize;
    }

}}
```

rects.h:

```
namespace SDLGamecore { namespace graphics {
    class Rects
    {
    private:
        //SDL_Rect rects[50];
        SDL_Rect* rects;
        int rectsSize = 0;
    public:
        Rects(int x, int y, int w, int h);
        ~Rects();
    public:
        SDL_Rect* getRects();
        int getRectsSize();
    };
}}

typedef struct SDL_Rect
{
    int x, y;
    int w, h;
} SDL_Rect;
```

Comment: Why do you use a pointer to `SDL_Rect` instead of a simple `SDL_Rect` in `Rects`? Currently, you are never allocating `rects` so your code will never work... If you want to use an array of `SDL_Rect`, use a `std::vector` or a `std::array` instead of `SDL_Rect*`.

Comment: Actually, I think you have a strong design flaw or misunderstanding of c++ classes - Your class is named `Rects` (with an **s**), you have a `rects` and `rectsSize`, so it looks like this is class that will hold multiple `SDL_Rect` **but** its constructor constructs a single `SDL_Rect`... What is the purpose of your `Rects` class?

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. My renderer need pointer from SDL_Rect. I try to make array struct with all rects in it. So i can render all rects with one drawcode. That is my plan :)

Comment: Yeah i name it Rects in futur i give new name shapes i think. Yeah the constructor need to make one element and add it to the SDL_Rect*. So i can make on my main file much elements with one constructor. Is that fold?

Comment: The constructor will construct a new instance, so you cannot "add" to rects using the constructor. Actually, I don't think you need this `Rects` class, simply use a standard container such as `std::vector`.

Comment: yeah that is my fold, i mean that is the same instance, is not i have see "damn". Then i use function from that class to make rects. Then i can add single instance on main and pick this function to create new rects! :) Thanks bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot "add" a `SDL_Rect` into `rects` using the constructor since the constructor create a new `rects`. Actually, I don't think you really need a custom structure to hold an array / list of `SDL_Rect`, simply use a `std::vector`, e.g. in your main:

```
std::vector<SDL_Rect> rects;
rects.push_back({1, 1, 4, 5}); // Add a SDL_Rect with x=1, y=1, w=4, h=5
rects.push_back({1, 4, 2, 3});
```

And then, when you need to call render:

```
SDL_RenderDrawRects(rendered, rects.data(), rects.size());
```

---

If you really want to use  a custom, e.g. `Shape` structure, then use a `std::vector` internally:

```
class Shape {
    std::vector<SDL_Rect> _rects;
public:
    Shape () { }

    void addRect (int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        _rects.push_back({x, y, w, h});
    }

    const std::vector<SDL_Rect>& getRects () const { return _rects; }

};
```

Then in `main`:

```
Shape shape;
shape.addRect(1, 1, 4, 5);
shape.addRect(1, 4, 2, 3);
SDL_RenderDrawRects(renderer, shape.getRects().data(), shape.getRects().size());
```

Or you could directly make `Shape` inherit from `std::vector<SDL_Rect>`:

```
class Shape: std::vector<SDL_Rect> {
    void addRect (int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        this->push_back({x, y, w, h});
    }
};

Shape shape;
shape.addRect(1, 1, 4, 5);
shape.addRect(1, 4, 2, 3);
SDL_RenderDrawRects(renderer, shape.data(), shape.size());
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice Answer. I Read and try it :)

Comment: ah i dont wanna make for any rect a new command: my plan is that: SDL_RenderDrawRects(renderer, rects, rectsSize); this handle all rects in SDL_Rect* p.  Your Custom code very interesting. i follow that i think :)

Comment: little Question why use vector? i mean struct with array is great or not?^^

Comment: @ivorysmoker See my edit. You can access the underlying array of an `std::vector` using `.data()`.

Comment: @ivorysmoker If you know the number of `SDL_Rect` at compile times, you can use a C-like array, e.g. `SDL_Rect rects[4]`, or better an `std::array<SDL_Rect, 4>`. If you don't know the number of `SDL_Rect` at compile times, you need a dynamically allocated array, which is exactly what `std::vector` is for. You could (but **should not**) use a `SDL_Rect*` with `new` but it is error-prone and you would have to write a lot of code (typically you need to allocate in your constructor, you need a custom copy/move-constructor and copy/move-assignment operator, a destructor, ...).

Comment: the underlying array is the other indexes? Sry dont understand that.

Comment: @ivorysmoker A `std::vector` is not a magic thing. Internally, it uses a `SDL_Rect*` and allocates memory using `new` and `delete` as you would do with your custom struct. To access the memory allocated (the underlying array), you can use `.data()`. `std::vector` does exactly what your code would do (dynamically allocates memory, delete when needed, etc.), but it does it much more efficiently and securely than you would (and than I or most of people would). Whenever you can (almost always), use a standard container instead of a custom versions.

Comment: yeah i know the number of SDL_Rect, for that u make rectsSize. :)

Comment: @ivorysmoker `rectsSize` is not a compile time constant, so you do not really know the number of `SDL_Rect` at compile times.

Comment: ok Thanks you for description, now i try bit :) Thank you very much!

Comment: any question const std::vector<SDL_Rect>& getRects() const { return rects; } is that cast? <SDL_Rect>Adress ? (cast to vector)?

Comment: @ivorysmoker No, this is a method returning a const reference to the internal vector.

Comment: Little fix on your code: std::vector<SDL_Rect>& getRects() 
   { 
    return rects; 
   } now it works very well :D "it says const is incompatible with Draw... ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for your custom code, that give me more experience :)

Comment: ah sry holt last question :P when im make this: std::vector<SDL_Rect> rects;
   std::vector<SDL_Rect> rects2; and then i use your function to getRects, then give me that all SDL_rects from rects and rects2? Is that correct? or i understand that fold :P?

Comment: @ivorysmoker No, it will only gives you `SDL_Rect` from `rects2`. You cannot "easily" concatenates two `std::vector` or two arrays in C++.

Comment: ah ok then i can make as example: `std::vector<MYOWNSTRUCT> test;` and new function to give all that vector stuff right? Or i can only make one vector? Only one vector is horrible :P I mean i have differend shapes with other vectors so i must have more then one vector :)

Comment: Ok i have testet, with other structs i can build second vectors with other get function, that work fine :) i thank you for teaching my :)

Comment: ah and now i understand your message xD u mean i cant get from 2 same vectors/structs all data :) ^^

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to allocate `rects`, which is just a pointer, in the constructor:

```
rects = new SDL_Rect[50];
```

That said, I'd not use an array / ptr but use `std::vector<SDL_Rect>`.

Comment: Step one works thanks :D One item renderering now. nice thanks men!